# "__ Cannot be resolved to a type" - JavaFX not working in eclipse with e(fx)clipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, efxclipse, eclipse-2019-09

I am running Eclipse 2019-09 on Windows 10 and have installed e(fx)clipse and I have the javaFX sdk in C:/Program Files/Java/javafx-sdk-13.0.1 
Whenever I create a new JavaFX project, the default code shows up, but everything (BorderPane, Stage, etc.) 'Cannot be resolved to a type'.
How do I fix this?

[image: All JavaFX objects are underlined in red, and under the console's 'Problems' tab, there are 11 warnings saying that each JavaFX object 'cannot be resolved to a type']

Comment: Does anything here help? https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ (look specifically at the _JavaFX and Eclipse_ section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have to setting java build path.

follow this step.

right click your java project folder -> build path -> configure build path -> Libraries ->
Modulepath -> add External Jar -> select jar file in javafx/lib.
like that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAIJZ.png)

add and close;

and 
right click your java project folder -> run as -> run configure -> argument -> vm argument -> put this on the box
--module-path "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Prog Math\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frn9H.png)

in "" put location of your javafx\lib that you add external jar;

Comment: This works! Thanks! Is there any way to make these settings a default, so that when I create a new JavaFX project, it works without me having to do this each time?

Comment: my teacher told me that java company or something about java have been tranfer to other hand so they change policy or some rule. Javafx or eclipse have to change due to the that rule so something have to disappear or change that why we have to setting very complicate. It happen this year that why it isn't fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**Go to-**
*eclipse -> menu -> Help -> Install New Software... then paste below link to install e(fx)clipse*

```
e(fx)clipse - IDE - Updatesite - http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/1.1.0/site/
```

Now, Add default external JAR jfxrt.jar in project using build path, given with Java from JDK installation directory.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar
```

If does not works on restarting eclipse then-

Go to- Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> JRE System Library -> Edit -> Change Execution Environment to JavaSE-1.8(jre) -> Apply